# Transformar Winforms a .dll e inyectarlo a un proceso

Tags: c#

tengo una aplicación en C# que decidí pasar a dll, la pregunta que tengo es si yo inyecto esa dll a un proceso (ejemplo notepad) podría usarla como si fuera un .exe?

A lo que me refiero seria usar la aplicación como si fuera un exe pero es una dll inyectada

Comment: existe una manera de implementar proyectos de esa manera, pero a soluciones propias en visual studio, en que entorno estas desarrollando?

Comment: csharp winforms

Comment: Si, me refiero a [entorno de desarrollo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entorno_de_desarrollo_integrado), no con que lo has desarrollado, Eclipse, VSCode, Visual Studio...

Comment: Visual Studio 2019

Comment: que es un dll inyectada? como esperas que notepad use tu dll?

Comment: que muestre la gui y se pueda usar como si fuera el exe normalmente

Comment: pero notepad no sabe hacer eso.. entiendo lo que queres, no entiendo el porque.. no podes inyectar una dll a cualquier cosa.. porque cualquier cosa no espera una inyeccion de una dll...

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0):

Existe una manera de implementar otros proyectos desarrollados en una misma Solución en [Visual Studio](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/).

1. Click derecho en referencias del proyecto que quieras implementar la dll o en su defecto el otro proyecto.
2. Agregar referencia.(Saldrá una ventana)
3. Selecciona en la pestaña de la izquierda proyectos, en el saldrán todos los proyectos disponibles dentro de una solución.
4. Marca el deseado y pulsa aceptar.

Ya tan solo con realizar un using puedes utilizar sus funcionalidades:

```
using NombreProyecto.NombreCarpetaElementoDeseado;
```

Si lo que deseas uno externo a tu solución:

1. Click derecho en referencias del proyecto que quieras implementar la dll o en su defecto el otro proyecto.
2. Agregar referencia.(Saldrá una ventana)
3. Pulsa en examinar.
4. Navega hasta el dll y selecciónalo
5. Aceptar.

No creo que esta segunda opción sea la que te funcione, ya que Windows Form no genera dll en si, genera un conjunto de elementos para la ejecución.

Esta es una manera de inyectar un proyecto dentro de otro, pero no creo que sea posible inyectar un winForm dentro de un IDE como notepad.